# True or false? If f is continuous on (a,b), then f(a) and f(b) can be defined so that f isintegrable on [a,b].

Tags: analysis

True  or  false?   If  f  is  continuous  on  (a,b),  then  f(a)  and  f(b)  can  be  defined  so  that  f  is integrable on [a,b].

I know the answer is false but why is it false?

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=\frac1x$ over $]0,1[$. Then, choosing any value for $f$ at $0$ will not change the fact that $f$ is not integrable on ]0,1[.